# How do I remove the hyperlink from a countdown iframe code I got from a countdown generator

Tags: iframe, timer, countdown

I have made this countdown on this website:
http://www.timeanddate.com/clocks/freecountdown.html

They gave me the iframe link to put it on my website, it is perfect as can be, only thing that is high unprofessional is for it to hyperlink to their free generator, the code is iframe, i'm not an expert on that and from what I've read you can't convert it to html, but how do I go about this? This is the code for the countdown script I made:

```
<iframe src="http://free.timeanddate.com/countdown/i38wb1iy/n240/cf12/cm0/cu4/ct0/cs0/ca0/cr0/ss0/cac000/cpc000/pcfff/tcfff/fs100/szw320/szh135/tatTime%20left%20to%20Event%20in/tac000/tptTime%20since%20Event%20started%20in/tpc000/mac000/mpc000/iso2012-08-20T00:00:00" frameborder="0" width="175" height="66"></iframe>
```

The source of the iframe code links to this page:
http://free.timeanddate.com/countdown/i38wb1iy/n240/cf12/cm0/cu4/ct0/cs0/ca0/cr0/ss0/cac000/cpc000/pcfff/tcfff/fs100/szw320/szh135/tatTime%20left%20to%20Event%20in/tac000/tptTime%20since%20Event%20started%20in/tpc000/mac000/mpc000/iso2012-08-20T00:00:00

which shows the countdown, but I still can't seem to find a way to take away the hyperlink or use the code in my own way for that matter.

If anyone could help me out and tell me how to work with this iframe script or be able to create an exact same countdown, as it shouldn't be that hard(it looks pretty simple), it would be highly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

The idea of iframe is 'a webpage inside a webpage'. So if you use the iframe you actually embed the third-party code. Besides - trying to remove a link would probably violate their terms of use.

Creating your own countdown in javascript wouldn't be difficult and can be a good exercise for a novice coder. Please look at Date reference:

http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_obj_date.asp

Note, that if you substract two dates, you get miliseconds delta of these dates. Using the modulo and division operators you can convert it into years/months/days. Then use e.g. jQuery methods:

http://api.jquery.com/category/manipulation/

to perform substitution on your page.

Comment: Hi zefciu, if I had more time I would take it to excercise and learn it myself, but at the moment I don't so I'm looking for a grab and paste method, I have emailed the people at timeanddate and they said they currently don't offer a way to get it without a hyperlink so I need to find something else...hmm...

Answer (score 0):

It's very simple. Select the full iframe through dream Weaver and down you can add your index page link, so that if anyone clicks on the timer from your home page, it will not divert. You will remain in your home page.

Answer (score 0):

add the following css

```
iframe{
 pointer-events: none;
}
```

if this doesn't work then try adding class or id in iframe tag.